# cygnus instance not reached from orion context broker

Tags: fiware, iot, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I have installed cygnus 0.8.2 on fiware image CentOS-7-x64, I subscribed to orion context broker using:

```
(curl 193.48.247.246:1026/v1/subscribeContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Fiware-Service: egmmqtt' --header 'Fiware-ServicePath: /egmmqttpath' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "sensors",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "sensors:switch2A"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
        "switch2A"
    ],
    "reference": "http://193.48.247.223:5050/notify",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONCHANGE",
            "condValues": [
                "switch2A"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "throttling": "PT1S"
}
EOF
```

No notification has reached cygnus and I got this error on  orionContextBroker logs:

```
time=2015-10-06T17:43:37.898CEST | lvl=WARNING | trans=1443447780-161-00000000423 | function=sendHttpSocket | comp=Orion | msg=clientSocketHttp.cpp[358]: Notification failure for 193.48.247.223:5050 (curl_easy_perform failed: Couldn't connect to server)
```

I dont know why the cygnus instance is not reached under the associated public IP adress. In fact I can't ping cygnus machine instance from Orion instance. Any ideas of what I have missed? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the security rules of cygnus instance the port on which cygnus is listenning (in my case 5050) has to be open so orion can reach cygnus instance.